# pygame on windows doesn't load sounds

Tags: pygame, windows

I had written a program using PyGame that should play sounds. I created sounds in Audacity, saved it as WAV (Microsost) signed 16 bit PCM. They are played well on Linux, but aren't loaded in Windows. There is exception:

```
    self.start_signal = pygame.mixer.Sound(open('start.wav'))
pygame.error: Unrecognized file type (not WAVE)
```

Same error if I try to use Ogg Vorbis:

```
    self.start_signal = pygame.mixer.Sound(open('start.ogg'))
pygame.error: OGG bitstream is not valid Vorbis stream!
```

But I can play sounds in both formats in Windows Media Player.

pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi

Comment: Have you initialized the mixer?

Comment: Yes, I have pygame.mixer.init() before pygame.mixer.Sound(open('start.ogg'))

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackExchange! Here, when a question is 'solved' we mark the most helpful answer as 'Accepted', and we don't change the title accordingly, as the whole interface is made so that the question is seen as clearly answered ('solved'). I rolled back your edit to reflect this. And you can mark your answer as accepted (this is perfectly acceptable here :)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out my mistake:

One should use

```
pygame.mixer.Sound('start.ogg')
```

instead of

```
pygame.mixer.Sound(open('start.ogg'))
```